# Loop through files in python

Tags: python, loops

I'm using python 3.6 on jupyter notebook.

I wrote this code to visualize some data.

```
from nilearn import plotting

DMN = plotting.plot_glass_brain("/Users/projets/rmap_seeds/average_rmap_DMN.nii.gz",
                            draw_cross = True, colorbar=True)
plt.show()
```

I have many different files where I want to visualize

I want to do a for loop so I don't have to write them all manually. I just put two examples here, but in fact I have hundreds.

I tried this :

```
image = {'average_rmap_DMN', 'average_rmap_CER'}

for i in image :
    image(i) = plotting.plot_glass_brain("/Users/projets/rmap_seeds/", 
    (image{i}), ".nii.gz", draw_cross = True, colorbar=True, threshold=0.7)
```

I get this error :

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks !

Comment: You get this error at `image(i) = plotting.plot_glass_brain...` this line?

Comment: Please look up how to create and access a list -- you've created a dictionary and you're accessing it incorrectly

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the task you're trying to accomplish. `image(i)` attempts to call `image` as a function (giving `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`, and `(image{i})` is trying to index with a set (I guess; that's how I mentally parse it but I don't know the exact route for it becoming a syntax error). `[i]` is the syntax for indexing.

Comment: I changed it for [] and now I get this error : `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: @bim1, my answer partially addresses that error.  Are you still having issues?

Comment: it still not working. I get this error : ` Cannot work out this file type  ` Maybe its my files that are not ok

Comment: @bim1, that's not a standard python error, so it's probably caused by the function `plotting.plot_glass_brain`.  Check the documentation for what arguments that expects, and that may make the error clearer.

Comment: I decide to separate my problem in two parts. First create a loop where I would change my file in the path and then use the create list of all the paths to use my function. Do you think it's a good idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Python uses square brackets for indexing rather than curly braces, so you should do `image[i]` to remove the syntax error.
However, in python iterating over a list returns list items rather than indices.
Indexing with `i` won't work, but you can use it directly:

```
for img in image:
    do_something(img)
```

Or alternatively using list comprehensions

```
[do_something(img) for img in image]
```

You can assign the results of the list comprehension to a new variable if you wish to continue modifying it, so your code would become

```
image = {'average_rmap_DMN', 'average_rmap_CER'}

res = [plotting.plot_glass_brain("/Users/projets/rmap_seeds/", 
    img, ".nii.gz", draw_cross = True, colorbar=True, threshold=0.7) 
    for img in image]
```

Lastly, judging by your code I'd recommend going through some introductory python tutorials.  Something like [this](https://bastibe.de/2013-01-20-a-python-primer-for-matlab-users.html) that is aimed at matlab users might be a good place to start, or [this one](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) for general info.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have the two expressions `image(i)`, and `image{i}`.

1. `image(i)` This is an issue because strings are not callable (you can't pass them arguments and have them work like functions). This is not a valid operation so an error would be thrown in that case. (The Python parser thinks you're trying to assign to a function call.)
2. `image{i}` This would be a syntax error. `{i}` is a set literal, so your expression is like having `x 1`, which is invalid syntax in Python. If you were looking for indexing, that would be `image[i]`.

But then there is the question: is `images` supposed to be a set or a dict? Because if it is a dictionary, then you are looping over the keys and it should be `images[i]`. However, if it is a set (which it appears to be what you're using), there are further problems.

1. Sets cannot be indexed
2. You cannot index a lists or strings by a string.

The indexing by strings issue, when you say `for string in strings:`, `string` is the string in the container, not an integer index to it.

So it seems like you have some more serious structural problems in your code. You should think of what data structures you need, and look into the methods of the builtin containers `list`, `dict`, `set`, `tuple`, etc.